# Splitting a nested dictionary based on value of nested key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a nested dictionary that I would like to split based on the value of `end qty`. I would like to only keep keys in which `'end qty' == 0`. I believe it can be done easily with dictionary comprehension, but I can't quite get it right.

```
import datetime
d = {
    'ID1' : {'start qty': 13 , 'end qty': 40},
    'ID2' : {'start qty': 10 , 'end qty': 0},
    'UD3' : {'start qty': 30 , 'end qty': 30},
    'ID4' : {'start qty': 20 , 'end qty': 0},
}    

print { k:v for k, v in d.items() if ['end qty'] == 0 }
```

Comment: `if  v['end qty'] == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `v` in the print statement, in this way

```
print { k:v for k, v in d.items() if v['end qty'] == 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this line instead:

```
print { k:v for k, v in d.items() if v['end qty'] == 0 }
```